# Loading a subimage from a tile map

Tags: java, arrays, image, awt, 2d

I'm trying to develop my first game. I have serious issues with loading Tiles extracted from a map.
Here's what I've coded so far, just willing to display the first tile.

```
public class TileMap {

    //FIELDS
    public int Tilemapx;
    public int Tilemapy;
    private int nRows = 8;
    private int nColumns = 8;
    public int TileWidth = Panel.WIDTH / nColumns;
    public int TileHeight = Panel.HEIGHT / nRows;
    public BufferedImage EntireMap;
    public BufferedImage SingleTile;

    public TileMap (){
        String EntireMappath = "res/Tiles.png";
        try {
            EntireMap = ImageIO.read(new File (EntireMappath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void drawTile (){
        for (int Tilemapx = 0; Tilemapx < Panel.WIDTH / nColumns; Tilemapx++){
            for (int Tilemapy = 0; Tilemapy < Pannel.HEIGHT / nRows; Tilemapy++){
                BufferedImage SingleTile = EntireMap.getSubimage(100, 100, Tilemapx, Tilemapy);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and, in the Panel class, I'm trying to draw the tile, but nothing appears (the first two images work as intended)

```
public void draw() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    g.drawImage(heroImg1, hero.cordX, hero.cordY, hero.diameter, hero.diameter, null);
    g.drawImage(tiles.SingleTile, 100, 200, tiles.Tilemapx, tiles.Tilemapx, null);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

Comment: In `TileMap.drawTile()`, you declared a local variable `SingleTile` and assigned sub image to it. You didn't assigned to the field `SingleTile`.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Hot-link to an image or generate one in code.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a method in `TileMap` that returns the appropriate sub image for a given tile. Then, in `draw`, you can call that method, obtain an image, and draw it on the graphics. If you would like to draw the whole board, simply use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void drawTile (){

// THIS IMAGE SingleTile SHOULD BE GLOBAL AND THIS IMAGE SHOULD BE RETURNED GLOBAL FROM A METHOD

BufferedImage SingleTile = EntireMap.getSubimage(100, 100, Tilemapx, Tilemapy);


// get the graphics context from what you want to paint onto
Graphics ga = OTHERIMAGE_OR_BUFFERSTRATEGY_OR_PANEL.getGraphics(); //or getDrawGraphics() for bufferstrategy

//then draw on it ga.drawImge(....................


}//END METHOD
```